# How to deal with repeating usage of same attributes

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, core-language

I am producing in my notebookfile many plots with the following example code:

```
plot = Framed[
   ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
    PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], Thickness[0.002]}, 
    FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", ""}}, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 40, 
      FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> 2000, 
    ImagePadding -> {{All, All}, {All, 50}}]];
```

How can I avoid to use for each new plot the same repeating attributes and only pass through the `data` to each new `ListPlot` call?

Comment: Why not write a subroutine collecting all your customizations?

Comment: Is this the only possibility, or can one pass through a bunch of attributes differently, so that still `ListPlot` is called?

Comment: see the documentation for `SetOptions`, it will let you do exactly what you ask for. It might be a good idea to remember what the original settings were so you can restore them once you are done. Restarting the kernel will clear those settings as well...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
    opts = Sequence[
      Joined -> True, 
      Frame -> True, 
      PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], Thickness[0.002]}, 
      FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", ""}}, 
      BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 40, 
      FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> 2000, 
      ImagePadding -> {{All, All}, {All, 50}}
    ];    

    plot1 = Framed[ ListPlot[data1, opts]];
    plot2 = Framed[ ListPlot[data2, opts]];
    ...
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for ... great thanks